# Odd behavior of stacked filter() calls

Tags: python, filter

So I'm getting some interesting behaviour from some filters stacked within a for loop.
I'll start with a demonstration:

```
>>> x = range(100)
>>> x = filter(lambda n: n % 2 == 0, x)
>>> x = filter(lambda n: n % 3 == 0, x)
>>> list(x)
[0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60, 66, 72, 78, 84, 90, 96]
```

Here we get the expected output. We have a range within a filter within a filter, and the filter conditions are stacking as we want them to. Now here comes my problem.
I have written a function for calculating the relative primes of a number. It looks like this:

```
def relative_primes(num):
    '''Returns a list of relative primes, relative to the given number.'''
    if num == 1:
        return []
    elif is_prime(num):
        return list(range(1, num))
    result = range(1, num)
    for factor in prime_factors(num):
        # Why aren't these filters stacking properly?                           
        result = filter(lambda n: n % factor != 0, result)
    return list(result)
```

For whatever reason, the filter is only being applied to the LAST factor in the list acquired from prime_factors(). Example:

```
>>> prime_factors(30)  
[2, 3, 5]  
>>> relative_primes(30)  
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```

We can see that no multiples of 2 or 3 were removed from the list. Why is this happening? Why does the above example work, but the filters in the for loop don't?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 3.x, `filter()` returns a generator instead of a list. As such, only the final value of `factor` gets used since all three filters use the same `factor`. You will need to modify your lambda slightly in order to make it work.

```
result = filter(lambda n, factor=factor: n % factor != 0, result)
```

Comment: Another concise option is `filter(factor.__rmod__, result)`, which, admittedly, makes the code slightly less readable.

Answer (score 1):

The evaluation of the iterators is lazy.  All filters will be evaluated only in the statement

```
return list(result)
```

By that time, the value of `factor` is the last prime factor.  The `lambda` functions only contain a reference to the local name `factor` and will use whatever value is assigned to that name at the time of execution.

One way to fix this is to convert to a list in every iteration.

As a sidenote, a much easier implementation of this function is

```
from fractions import gcd
def relative_primes(n):
    return [i for i in range(1, n) if gcd(n, i) == 1]
```

**Edit**: If you are after performance instead of simplicity, you can also try this one:

```
def relative_primes(n):
    sieve = [1] * n
    for i in range(2, n):
        if not sieve[i] or n % i:
            continue
        sieve[::i] = [0] * (n // i)
    return list(itertools.compress(range(n), sieve))
```

Comment: THIS. Okay, I figured it might have to do with the local name 'factor'. Thanks a lot for this.

Also, I know a solution using gcd's is better, but I've this one to actually be faster. I have a few versions of the algorithm.

Comment: Everything works. Also, I just ran some tests, and my algorithm is over twice as fast as the one you proposed, even when I added an additional check for prime numbers.

Comment: @fosskers: Didn't know you are after performance.  Added another simple implementation, which should also be fast.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly and *Two integers are relatively prime if they share no common positive factors (divisors) except 1. Using the notation  to denote the greatest common divisor, two integers a and b are relatively prime if gcd(a,b)==1.* then you can use the [fractions](http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html) module in the following way.

```
from fractions import gcd

num = 30
relative_primes = filter(lambda x: gcd(x,num) == 1, xrange(1,num))
```